# Mathematical Analysis integral inequality

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a nonnegative continuous function on $[0,1]$ , and $f$ nondecrease. Then for any $0<\alpha<\beta<1$ , we have $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\geq\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)dx$ , and $\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}$  is the biggest number satisfying the inequality.

Comment: Please formulate your question as a question. What do you want to prove? Also sketch what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show that the average value of $f(x)$ on $[\alpha,1]$ is at least the average value of $f(x)$ on $[\alpha,\beta]$.

Comment: I want to know how to prove that $\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}$ be the biggest number satisfying the inequality

Comment: I know. I just don't want to do your whole homework problem for you.

Comment: I can pove the inequality , I only can't konw how to explain the last one.

Comment: Equality holds for the function that is 1 on $[\alpha,1]$ and zero on $[0,\alpha)$. Approximate this function by continuous functions.